# Setting Values of textboxes that were created using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, textbox

I had a form in which I made some textboxes using javascript. Basically I gave a button and Onclick of that button I add a Textbox using Javascript.
These values were then taken in a string on the server side and stored in different List columns.

Now I want to create Edit Functionality. So I have to retrieve values from the List COlumns and Insert it in the Textboxes.
This was easy when my controls were server controls but How can I do this for textboxes that were created using Javascript.

I am new to client side scripting. Any help will be appreciated.

All I need is a way to get the values from the List COlumn and then create those textboxes again with those values.

PS: Please advise if you wana see the code for how I have created the textboxes and got those values on the server side.
Thanks!

Javascript Code to create Textboxes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function GetDynamicTextBoxB(value)
                { return '<input name = "DynamicTextBoxB" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBoxB(this)" />' }
                var y = 0;
                function AddTextBoxB() {
                    if (y < 10) {
                        var div = document.createElement('DIV'); div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBoxB(""); document.getElementById("TextBoxContainerB").appendChild(div);                       
                                 }
                    else        {
                        alert("Only 10 CSPs can be added")
                                 } y++
                  }
                function RemoveTextBoxB(div)
                { document.getElementById("TextBoxContainerB").removeChild(div.parentNode); }
                function RecreateDynamicTextboxesB() {
                    var values = eval('<%#Values%>');
                    if (values != null) {
                        var html = ""; for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                        { html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBoxB(values[i]) + "</div>"; } document.getElementById("TextBoxContainerB").innerHTML = html;
                    }
                }
                $("#tabs-1").ready(RecreateDynamicTextboxesB);
                //                //  window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxesB;
           </script>
```

Code Behind to Get these values on the server side and storing in List COlumns

```
string PartyACSP1 = string.Empty, PartyACSP2 = string.Empty, PartyACSP3 = string.Empty, PartyACSP4 = string.Empty, PartyACSP5 = string.Empty, PartyACSP6 = string.Empty, PartyACSP7 = string.Empty, PartyACSP8 = string.Empty, PartyACSP9 = string.Empty, PartyACSP10 = string.Empty;
                if (textboxValues != null)
                {
                    PartyACSP1 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 0);
                    PartyACSP2 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 1);
                    PartyACSP3 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 2);
                    PartyACSP4 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 3);
                    PartyACSP5 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 4);
                    PartyACSP6 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 5);
                    PartyACSP7 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 6);
                    PartyACSP8 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 7);
                    PartyACSP9 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 8);
                    PartyACSP10 = safeGetString(textboxValues, 9);
                }


                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSPColumn] = PartyACSP1;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP2Column] = PartyACSP2;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP3Column] = PartyACSP3;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP4Column] = PartyACSP4;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP5Column] = PartyACSP5;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP6Column] = PartyACSP6;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP7Column] = PartyACSP7;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP8Column] = PartyACSP8;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP9Column] = PartyACSP9;
                newISDAAgreement[Constants.PartyACSP10Column] = PartyACSP10;
```

Comment: Please share the code you got already.

Comment: please share code please.

Answer (score 0):

while retrieving data from list column you must have a map of the data for which you want to create an edit functionality. for e.g.
suppose you have the data

listcolumn = {'data1': 123, 'data2': 234, 'data3': 345}

so just you can loop into that data and create the textboxes with its value in it.

for(key in listcolumn){
create a textbox and its value from listcolumn[key] (this will give you the value for that particular textbox)
}

or if are not comfortable with the dictionary thing 
 you can use the either way i.e. data is list form

listcolumn = [123,234,345]

for(data in listcolumn){
   create a textbox and insert value in it. 
}

but i would be preffered that you use JSON format from server side to front end
and you can parse the data using JSON.parse(data). And will get the dictionary as an object.

Comment: and yes that was just an assumption from the above scenario that you have explained. please share the code if not satisfied

Comment: So I have the value from the List Column, How WOuld I then Create a textbox in my UI to display these values?

Comment: Basically have a hidden field on the page which is a server side control, populate this with the JSON that Tajinder provided, then on the button click parse this JSON and iterate over it and create each textbox and populate the value.

Comment: And how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a different architecture: 
knockout.js - for a client-sisde, where you could develop your MVVM,
MVC - as the app type,
Ajax to send the queries to the server side for your ops like Loading,Saving, etc.